# How to get all eclipse's linked folders from the IProject programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What I need is API for getting all [linked folders](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm) from the [IProject](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProject.html) programmatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `isLinked()` method of the `IFolder` (or any `IResource`) to test if it is a link.

You can use the `accept(IResourceVistor)` method of `IProject` to look at all its children to find all the folders.

You can also use `accept(IResourceProxyVisitor)` to do the scan which may be faster. The `IResourceProxy` interface this uses also has an `isLinked()` method.